# why is a transaction rolled back if it exists in a rescue/raise clause in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, exception

I have a simple exception handler as follows

```
begin
  # code
rescue Exception
  # Write to database
  raise
end
```

The `write to database` is rolled back if `raise` is called. Is what I'm attempting to do possible?

## Edit

Write to database does the following

```
Question.create(
  notification_id: 1,
  text: 'test'
)
```

Very simple.

Comment: It probably should not..what's inside the rescue block?

Comment: Try to create it from console `Question.create!( notification_id: 1, text: 'test' )` notice the `!`(bang) it will give you reason for rollback..mostly there's a validation error.

Comment: I think I know what the problem is. If I'm wrong please let me know. Anything between `begin` and `recsue` will be rolled back. I'm calling `raise` in the rescue block. Rail will go about handling the exception itself and when it does, my entire exception exists between the `begin` and `rescue` block that rails provides. Therefore it makes sense that Rails will rollback my write to database.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot rollback unless you use a transactions like follows

```
raise ActiveRecord::Rollback, "Call tech support!"
```

In your case, May be you have validated attributes in model (Question) and it get failed. 
You can check errors like :

```
questions=Questions.new(...)
errors = questions.errors.full_messages if questions.invalid?
```

Comment: How does a `new` object has `errors` object? Did you try to run that in your console?

Comment: Yes. It does. It gives us validation errors if we have any. If record is not getting saved in database because of validations, then we can get its validation errors by using `questions.errors` . Please follow the link for detail explanation : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/active_record_validations_callbacks.html

Comment: thanks for the reference, I wish you had read it first. Let me quote a note from section 2.4 `Note that an object instantiated with new will not report errors even if it’s technically invalid, because validations are not run when using new.`